# How to run entire JUnit Test Suite from within code

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4

In eclipse, with JUnit 4, you can right click a project or package and click Run as JUnit Test, and it will run all the JUnit tests within that grouping. Is there a way to do this same thing from within the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use packages in junit such as [JUnitCore](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html) like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List tests = new ArrayList();
    tests.add(TestOne.class);
    tests.add(TestTwo.class);

    for (Class test : tests){
        runTests(test);
    }
}

private static void runTests(Class test){
    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(test);
    for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()){
        System.out.println(failure.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use JUnit Suite:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
// Put your Test Case Class here
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    JunitTest1.class,
    JunitTest2.class,
    JunitTest3.class
})
public class JunitTestSuite {}
```

Then create a main method to run it.

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class JunitTestSuiteRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(JunitTestSuite.class);
    for (Failure fail : result.getFailures()) {
        System.out.println(fail.toString());
    }
    if (result.wasSuccessful()) {
        System.out.println("All tests finished successfully...");
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

JUnit provides the [test Suite](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html#juniteclipse_testsuite). Give that a try.

```
[...]
public class TestCaseA {
    @Test
    public void testA1() {
        // omitted
    }
}

[...]
public class TestCaseB {
    @Test
    public void testB1() {
        // omitted
  }
}

[...]
@RunWith(value=Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses(value = {TestCaseA.class})
public class TestSuiteA {
}

[...]
@RunWith(value=Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses(value = {TestCaseB.class})
public class TestSuiteB {
}

[...]
@RunWith(value = Suite.class )
@SuiteClasses(value = {TestSuiteA.class, TestSuiteB.class})
public class MasterTestSuite{
}
```

Comment: Many of my tests have the same name, so this option won't work as well. I'm really looking for code that has the same functionality as clicking "Run as JUnit Test" for the project or package.

Comment: This approach require you to mention all classes.