# Running JUnitCore with instances instead of classes

Tags: java, junit4

I'm looking to run **JUnit 4.12+** programmatically, and a cursory search for doing so yielded (amongst many other similar posts) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24946254/4009451), which prescribes the following basic solution:

```
@RunWith(Suite)
@Suite.SuiteClasses ({
    MyTestClass1.class,
    MyTestClass2.class
})
public class MyTestSuite {
}

Result testResults = JUnitCore.runClasses(MyTestSuite.class);
```

...and I was able to get this working, no sweat. So far so good!

Problem is: I have some pretty sophisticated test classes that need to be instantiated/injected with very specific properties at runtime...not something that can be done from inside a no-arg constructor. But the above method (specifying to just run *any* old instance of a set of classes) doesn't allow you to instantiate your test classes, configure them, and *then* run them.

Is there a way to do this? I couldn't find anything looking at the [JUnit API](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html). I am looking for something like:

```
MyTestClass1 mtc1 = new MyTestClass1(...);
MyTestClass2 mtc2 = new MyTestClass2(...);
Result testResults = JUnitCore.run(mtc1, mtc2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with a custom `Runner` with sample (Groovy pseudo-code) as follows:

```
class MyRunner extends Runner {
    @Override
    Description getDescription() {
        return null
    }

    @Override
    void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        // LoginTests.class is a test class I want to run
        LoginTests loginTests = new LoginTests(<my args here>)

        Description description = Description.createSuiteDescription(LoginTests)
        notifier.fireTestStarted(description)
        try {
            log.info("About to doSomething()...")
            loginTests.doSomething()
            log.info("Did it...")
            notifier.fireTestFinished(description)
        } catch(Throwable throwable) {
            log.info("doSomething() failed...")
            notifier.fireTestAssumptionFailed(new Failure(description, throwable))
        }
    }
}

Result testResults = new JUnitCore().run(Request.runner(new MyRunner()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need custom runner to achieve that. Junit 4/5 comes with third party runner that can perform dependency Injection for Constructors and Methods. Few runner which are pretty popular are Mockito(MockitoJUnitRunner) and SpringJUnit4ClassRunner in case you are using Spring. You can check out custom runner and implementation details at: 
https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Custom-runners

Comment: Thanks @user8185075 (+1) - are you talking about [this method](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html#run(org.junit.runner.Runner)) (`public Result run(Runner runner)`) by any chance?

Comment: I was talking about ParameterResolver [http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ParameterResolver.html] . It defines the API for test extensions to dynamically resolve parameters at runtime.